# How to post html outside your domain?

Tags: php, html, forms, url, post

Let's say we are making a form that we want to have on domain1.com and we want to post it to domain2.com.  Can this be done?

```
<form method="post" action="domain2.com/receivepost.php">
    <input type="text" name"text" />
    <input type="submit value="submit" />
</form>
```

domain2.com/receivepost.php

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the full URL (including protocol) in the `action` attribute of your `form` tag as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="http://domain2.com/receivepost.php">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

On the PHP side, you can check for POST data as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    echo $_POST['text'];
}
```

Notice that the `name` attribute of the input tag is `text`.

Comment: So this is basically how apps do this?  Pretty neat...  and the same I guess works for 'https'   = https://domain2.com/receivepost.php

Comment: Yeah, you can specify either `http` or `https`... The way you had things setup, it would post to a path relative to the current URL.  For example, if the form was located on `http://yoursite.com/form.html` then your action would have posted to `http://yoursite.com/domain2.com/receivepost.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify full URL if you want to send request to specific domain

```
<form method="post" action="http://domain2.com/receivepost.php">
    <input type="text" name"text" />
    <input type="submit value="submit" />
</form>
```

Or you can send to relative (for your domain) path:

```
<form method="post" action="receivepost.php">
    <input type="text" name"text" />
    <input type="submit value="submit" />
</form>
```